# Trouble with TI DRV8825 output

Tags: avr, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

There is a electrical scheme of my board:

[image: Electrical scheme]

That's what I see on output, when stepper motor is not connected / is connected:

[image: With_eng]
[image: Without_eng]

The stepper motor doesn't move and produces a squeaking sound and vibration, but I feel torque a little bit on stepper motor. Can't figure out what's wrong.

V motor is 12V, VREF = ~1.1V. Stepper motor 17HS4401.

There is a PCB layout:

[image: PCB layout Top layer]
[image: PCB layout bottom layer]

**UPD:**
*Now I put the driver on breakout board and repeated Polulu scheme. Still didn't succeed.*

This oscillogram is for STEP pin of DRV8825:
*STEP pulse duration HIGH and LOW are both more than 3us*

[image: STEP]

This is for R10 and R11 (mean amplitude is near to 100mV):

[image: R1011]

[image]

Comment: You possibly have the step sequence wrong..

Comment: What is R26 set to? What max drive current are you expecting?

Comment: Also, you might provide a link or datasheet for the motor you are using and tell us how you have the coils connected. Is the lower image captured on the same sweep setting as the upper image (and with the same step rate)?

Comment: Current limitation is correct, coil connection is correct. Pictures are taken with same settings.

SM working properly with 'Polulu DRV8825 Carrier' on the same settings.

I have two difference between 'Polulu DRV8825 Carrier' and my board:
1. R26 is 20 kOhm (instead of 10)
2. C11 is 10 nF 25V (instead of 10 nF 50V)

I try to use 100 nF 50V instead of C11 (don't have proper cap right now) but it didn't help.

Comment: "Current limitation is correct, coil connection is correct."" R26 is 20 kOhm" ... I guess if you are going to skirt around the questions as asked, you are on your own. Good luck.

Comment: R26 is a trimmer resistor. It is configured in such a way that the output voltage on pin ARef/BRef is about 0.4 V what is equal 0.8 A for current limit. So yeah, I think that current limitation is correct.

Comment: Just a note on your schematic: you have nFAULT and nSLEEP connected together, while Fault is output and Sleep is input and they should be controlled/sensed separately.

Comment: @GAttuso there's nothing wrong with that connection. It's also used on the Pololu breakout board. Basically in the event of a fault it puts the chip to sleep. However if the sleep pin is driven from the AVR, the connection does nothing.

Comment: What step rate are you running at? What motors do you have?

Comment: PCB layout would be useful to see also.

Comment: Try increasing the C13 to 100uF.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter
Ok, that make sense, thank you. Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: A good next diagnostic step would be to replace the stepper motor with 2 power resistors (12V/0.5A -> 24 ohms or 20-25 ohms) using one for each coil.  That will ensure things are basically working.  If that works, use a 10ohm power resistor for each coil and test the current limiting.

Comment: 1. The replacement of C13 did not help;
2. Step rate is 100ms;
3. Fulling Motors 28SH51-0674A.

Comment: @A.Shirkov The GND symbol pointing upwards in the schematic makes me cringe. It is considered good style if it points downwards

Comment: @Manu3l0us Thanks, I'll take this into consideration.

Comment: The tracks that should pass a significant current are too thin and long. Low-current and high-current sections of the circuit should not have shared tracks in the power supply.

Comment: The amplitude of the signal on the oscillogram should occupy a significant part of the screen (70% -90%). Please select Volt/DIV correctly and update them. It is also important to know the current on the coils of the motor and not the voltage. A voltage proportional to the current of the coils can be measured on R10 and R11. At current 1A amplitude of voltage should reach 0,1V. This value is sufficient to measure the oscilloscope.

Comment: @AltAir OP updated. I get 100mV on R10/R11 when Vref is ~1.1V (it is ~2A current limitation for my scheme).

Comment: What is the voltage on the pins 4 or 11 of the driver? Please make an oscillogram. 5 volt of the power supply is a low level for this driver.

Comment: Vmot is 12V, so on pins 3,4,11 is 12V too. By "logic level is 5V" I meant that logical HIGH level is 5V.

Comment: The first two oscillograms show that the amplitude of the voltage at the driver output is only 5V. I saw that you are declaring 12V but check if it is true.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see. Probably there is mistake in probe multiplier settings or something else I think (cuz on old pictures there is a 12V). But I will double-check this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are using the IC outside the datasheet suggestions.

[image]

Where with a more degraded accuracy, where already between 15% to 25% nominally, you can confuse the controller, considering the relatively low current setting (which seems to be to 1.6A according to the comments). This heavily depends on how is made the layout, as well as any interference with the control IC itself if not even EMI withint the MCU itself, mismatching some control signals. With Atmel parts and huge EMI from motors, this could temporary brick the MCU.

A bit more on your scope screes. Also when the driver is actually output power, it generates a proper signal according to the input squarewave. So what you see (and we don't because the scope time division is too large in your picture) is probably the controller struggling with something. When is not connected to a motor, it is very likely that the output will be simply following the input.

So to finish, to know what actually is going on here, you shall at least: check the mode pins, make the stepper working with a reference within proper values, provide windings characteristics (stepper's datasheet) and, last but not least, a zoom of the oscilloscope capture when the motor is producing the squeaking sound.

Comment: Current mode pins configuration: RESET - High, SLEEP - High, ENABLE - Low, M0 - Low, M1 - Low, M2 - Low, DIR - Low.
[Engine datasheet](http://www.fullingmotor.com/product/hy/15.html). Oscillograms was updated in OP. "make the stepper working with a reference within proper values" - I do not quite understand what I need to do. If we are talking about V3P3OUT and R26, now I have 10kOhm trimmer instead of 20 kOhm, and  current limit is now set to 0.5 A.

Comment: @A. Shirkov R10 and R11 on PCB layout must be directly and closely connected to GND of the U5. Please add scope shot on STEP of the U5, R10, R11.

Comment: OP was updated. On R10 and R11 I do not see anything as I expected (btw the voltage drop on this resistors is insignificantly small).

Comment: @A. Shirkov you must change the Volt/DIV for the  CH1 of the oscilloscope for small signal.

Comment: Try to apply a <1kHz signal to STEP pin and see if something happens. What I see seems glitch of 8V on 5V logic, so try also to protect the pin. R26 is not important, I need to know what is the voltage out of the trim R26 and not its resistor value. But if 0.5A is correct, you are providing 0.25V of reference, where the minimum advised is 1V.

Comment: @AltAir both of STEP pulse duration HIGH and LOW are >3us

Comment: @thexeno VREF = 0.25V, right, but I can't find any reference to 1V recommended in datasheet. With an input signal of 900Hz, the sound changes and engine stops working in slow decay mode.

Comment: For the reference to 1V, check the table 7.3 in my answer. Start with a frequency of 50Hz maximum, do not go from the higher to the lower. But again, put FIRST the IC in its suggested operating conditions.

Comment: @thexeno OP updated. I place driver on breakout board (like in Polulu scheme), Vref now is >1V, check logic stuff and code. Still didn't succeed.

Comment: Ok, what about the frequency?